# How can I view a PHP file without having to upload it to my ftp?

Tags: php

This is probably embarrassing short-sighted or just completely wrong, but I've made a header.php and a footer.php file and then an index.php file that calls them.  Is there a way to view that index.php file from my desktop?

Comment: Install apache and php and run the file. Or.. use a tool like WAMP or AMPPS to create a virtual server on your machine. (assuming your on windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an Apache Server:

XAMPP - http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html

This will install MySQL, PHPMYADMIN, Apache, PHP on your computer, so you can just upload files to

> C:\xampp\htdocs\

and browse to :

> 127.0.0.1 OR localhost

via a browser with Apache Service running.

^ Assumes you are on Windows.

Another assumption if you was on a linux box (Ubuntu For example)

http://www.howtoforge.com/ubuntu_lamp_for_newbies

Answer (score 3):

Use local webserver stack like [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html)
This will allow you to view PHP Pages without having to upload them to your Server

Answer (score 1):

Install a webserver with support for PHP on your desktop.

Apache is a good choice. There are bundles of Apache + PHP available for most operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to install a web server/PHP stack on your desktop.  You could looks at something like WAMP (for windows) or MAMP (for Mac) to do this.  Or if you happen to be using Linux just install Apache and PHP directly on your machine.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on windows use [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) If you are on mac use [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html). For linux use [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) Plus read this [How Web Servers Work](http://www.howstuffworks.com/web-server.htm)

Comment: Why not configure a LAMP Server directly from CLi?